# Capture Session Timeout Event in Sitecore Marketing Automation

Tags: marketing-automation

I am working on Sitecore 9.0.2 and we have a requirement to send a reminder email through marketing automation. We have a scenario where contact will land on registration page and provide email/password, system will register the user and redirect it on profile page. In many cases user reached on profile page but does not provide details. In this case a reminder mail will go. In marketing automation tool, i am enrolling a contact while registration will finish and waiting for either session expired or profile submission event. once session expired before the profile submission, i'll send a email. In this flow i have following questions.

1.) I am not able to find a default rule to find out if tracking session has expired. I found a rule for page session end (/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/Session end) but not sure this is limited to page or tracking session expired. Any suggestion for this. if its not available by default, may i have to raise a custom event explicitly while session expired pipeline get executed.

2.) i'll put a custom listener with two rules (session expired or profile submitted) after contact's enrollment, in this scenario how i can pass details to next activity which event has triggered customer listener ?

please suggest if overall scenario can be handled in different way in marketing automation. Thanks

Sourabh K.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outcome function to check contact submit or not submit page. No path for session expired with timeout set, and Yes path when user submit page.

[image: Outcome item]
Then make contact pass it:

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference("sitecoreextranet", "Contact Email here");
            var existingContact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(reference, new ContactExpandOptions(new string[] { PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey }));
            if (existingContact != null)
            {
                var channelId = Guid.Parse("{52B75873-4CE0-4E98-B63A-B535739E6180}");
                var interaction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Contact, channelId, "xConnectIntro Console App");
                Guid outcomeId = Guid.Parse("outcome ID here"); // ID of outcome item
                var outcome = new Sitecore.XConnect.Outcome(outcomeId, DateTime.UtcNow, "USD", 100.00m);
                interaction.Events.Add(outcome);
                client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                client.Submit();
            }
        }
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Survey Completed", this);
        return View("SurveyCompleted");
```

Then you can add next activity in Yes path to continue.